Hamiltonian cycles and paths in a 3D cube
If an edge is fixed and is directed, how many hamiltonian paths will there be in a cube or an 8-vertexed graph? 6 vertices are not yet traversed. And how many of them will be hamiltonian cycles?

Do you know how many Hamiltonian paths (or, cycles) there are in a cube, without the restriction? Since all the edges are equivalent, it shouldn't be hard to work out how many of the paths (or, cycles) contain any one particular directed edge.
